# Adding new matrix block will result in wrong locale

Tags: matrix, localization, admin

I have matrix fields where I dont have translation on the whole matrix, but only on the fields within a certain block. Nothing complicated or fancy. When I add a new matrix block in the admin, it will result in a locale that is not the same as the one I'm editing at the moment: I have two locales installed (sv and en). Everything works fine. But its just that when I'm editing the swedish (sv) entries I can see that the locale-indicator next to the matrix text-field says "en". But when I edit the swedish locale, I want to start adding text in the locale that I'm editing at the moment.

I'm using Craft Pro 2.4.2668

[image: screenshot]

Above is a screenshot from the admin, with the locale-indicator (screenshot taken right after klicking the "+ Menu item"-button

Comment: and just for the record: in Settings > Content Locales, sv is ABOVE en... But this doesnt seem to matter...

Comment: and I tried it in 2.3.???? where the same problem occured...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a UI bug when saving a *new* Matrix block in an new entry.

If you save, the data is saved into the correct locale and the fields in Matrix blocks will display their correct locales (in your case `sv`).

Comment: Ok, then I know that I'm not doing anything wrong. Thanks alot for the answer! Sorry for asking, but is there a quick-n-dirty fix that I could put in?

Comment: Nothing I'm aware of... sorry!